# Loop through an array and print how many thimes it gets repeated in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm leaning Kotlin, and I'm wondering if there is a better, simpler and not that complicated way to do this in Kotlin? I need to Write a Kotlin program that loops through an array and generates a histogram based on the numbers in it.The results should look like this(vertically):

```
1: *****
2: **
3: **
4:
5: *
```

And this is what I did:

```
fun main() {
    val myArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1)
     
     for(num in 1..5){   
        println("")
        print("$num: ")
        for(element in myArray) {
            if(element == num){
                print("*")
            }
     }    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will be simpler, but you can do something like this:

```
fun main() {
    val myArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1)

    for (num in 1..5) {
        println("")
        
        val count = myArray.count { it == num }
        val entries = if (count > 0) "*".repeat(count) else ""
        print("$num: $entries")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is basically how I'd write the OP's version (lots of ways to approach it!) - you don't need to do that `count` check though, `"*".repeat(0)` will give you an empty string anyway. You could probably just do `println("$num: ${"*".repeat(count)}")`, it's short enough to be neat!

Comment: Thank you! , the answer is great and it works, but I don't know why the program didn't accept it and I try with 3 different ways to do it and nothing >.<

Comment: What do you mean "program didn't accept it"? Is this a code challenge or something? Maybe there is something else which is different?

Comment: Yes, it is a practice excercise, you put the code on the program to evaluate it, tried different ways but nothing

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`eachCount`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html) function to find the count of items in a list.

This is what I came up with:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    
    val map = listOf(1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1)
        .groupingBy{ it }
        .eachCount()
        
    (1..5).forEach { 
        
        print("\n${it}:")
        
        map[it]?.let { count -> repeat(count){ print("*") } }       
        
    }
    
}
```

You can see the code here: https://pl.kotl.in/91d7pWDGe

Kotlin Koans is a good place you can learn by writing code. Here is the Koans for Collections: https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Collections/Introduction/Task.kt

Comment: Yeah a big part of learning the "more elegant" ways of doing stuff in Kotlin is getting your head around the `kotlin.collections` (and `kotlin.text`) standard library functions. There's a lot of neat stuff in there to help you wrangle data concisely instead of having to write the whole logic out in a `for` loop (not that there's anything wrong with that, the solution in the question is nice). I think for this answer, it would be better to loop over `(1..5)` explicitly - the OP wants missing numbers included, and if *5* happened to be missing from the data, it would change the range, y'know?

Comment: Good catch @cactustictacs! It has to be `(1..5)` to show all 5 numbers all the time. Updated the code.